# How can I detect the main executable's function definitions from a dynamic library - particularly malloc

Tags: c, linux, gcc

So libgcc will use the application's malloc and free, if it has defined one, in order to satisfy the application's need to call free() after certain library calls, eg realpath.

Within my dynamic library, I really don't want to use that application malloc/free, because I don't trust it generally - I'm happy to use libgcc's implementation of malloc, which is what most applications use, so I declared my own malloc() function that calls libgcc's implementation via dlsym().

All was going well until... I want to call realpath (and perhaps others)! As a simple fix, I need a way to do the equivalent of dlsym() but on the main executable (which I don't own) to get the application's implementation of free, if any. Does such a thing exist?

I know it must, because the dynamic linker "does the right thing", but is it accessible to mere mortal programmers, and how?

In the particular case of realpath, I know I can provide a buffer, but that comes with its own unknown dangers about buffer size. For some other calls I can't do that.

I can also go down the winding path of symbol renaming with objcopy, but I'd prefer not to, if possible.

[laters]
I do take your point on malloc being possibly defined by another dynamic library, and I would want to use that version, while the application still uses its compiled in version (I have seen that it does continue to use it, even if tcmalloc is preloaded, for example.

I guess that extends the question to ask if any library has defined malloc, and if the application has defined malloc, I want to cherry-pick which version of malloc/free I use in each place in my code to match the behaviour of libgcc when necessary, and not when not, so I want to be able to get a reference to them both.

In the short term I have resolved my current issue by replacing realpath() in my code with a version that pre-defines the buffer using my malloc, before calling the libgcc implementation, but I feel this is very much a band-aide.

Comment: What about just relinking to the new library? This is not so different to many tools that check double free, use after allocation and so on.

Comment: Thanks @Giacomo Ideally we want to avoid any hassle with the app, as it isn't ours, so relinking isn't really an option for me. If I could get the apps built without the dodgy malloc everyone would be happy! :-)

Answer (score 1):

The interposing `malloc` can come from anywhere, not just the executable.  It could be a shared object referenced by a `DT_NEEDED` entry in the dynamic section of another object, or a library injected into the process image using `LD_PRELOAD`.

In general, many libraries have functions which allocate something which then has to be deallocated using `free`.  Software ported to Windows will not do this (because DLLs have separate heaps there), but otherwise, it is not uncommon.  There is not just `realpath`, there is also `strdup`, `asprintf`, and probably I bunch of other functions I do not remember.

In your case, you should just call `free` on such pointers, and use a different name for your own memory deallocation functions.  Once `malloc` has been interposed, it is not possible to safely use the original libc allocator because it has not been properly initialized.  For example, if you call the glibc `malloc` function in a process which uses a different, interposed `malloc`, then `malloc` will not be thread-safe: the initialization is not thread-safe because the implementation knows that `pthread_create` will call `malloc` before creating the first new thread, thereby initializing `malloc` while the process is single-threaded.  Which is why there is no synchronization in the initialization code.

(libgcc does not provide `malloc`, by the way.  It comes from libc/glibc.)

Comment: The problem with this being that we rely on lots of library code, etc that we use, which just blindly uses "some malloc".
If some other module wants to define an implementation of malloc, I'm happy using that - there are some good tools out there.
What I'm finding is that the LD_PRELOAD and such do NOT replace the malloc defined in the main executable, and realpath, for example, still calls that main app supplied version. To be honest I am surprised that it "all just works" as it stands!

Comment: Yes, I am aware that there are numerous other functions that could be an issue. "Luckily", as the code is mainly c++, we tend not to use those C utility library functions that you mention, and are only impacted by the few system calls that contain the magical phrase "The caller should deallocate this buffer using free(3)."

Comment: I do take your point on malloc being defined by another dynamic library, and I guess that extends the question to ask if any library has defined malloc, and if the application has defined malloc, I want to cherry-pick which version of malloc I use in my code, so I want to be able to get a reference to them both.